# What is the expression of $n$ that equals to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

My problem is:
What is the expression in $n$ that equals to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$?

Thank you very much~

Comment: There isn't one.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean algebraic expression in $n$? I guess there is no algebraic expression in $n$ that satisfies the equation. But I am wondering if there is a transcendetal expression in $n$ that does.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't think there is a "closed" form. You can give a good approximation using the [Euler-McLaurin Summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) formula though:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{j^2}  = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6} - \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O}(\dfrac{1}{n^3})$$

(If you need more accuracy you can include more terms from the summation formula to give the coefficients of the lower order terms)

Note: The Euler McLaurin Summation formula only tells us that

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{j^2}  = C - \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O}(\dfrac{1}{n^3})$$

for some constant $\displaystyle C$.

We know by other means that $\displaystyle C = \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$, for instance, see this for a multitude of ways: [Different methods to compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/different-methods-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n2)

Answer (score 6):

I not sure of the thrust of your question but maybe the generalised harmonic numbers are what you want
$$ H_{n,r} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^r} , $$

and in particular $H_{n,2}$

You can find more information [here,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) including a very nice identity for $H_{n,2}$ by B. Cloitre.

Comment: Alternatively, you have the expression in terms of the trigamma function: $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\psi^{(1)}(n+1)$

Comment: I am guessing OP is looking for a simpler formula than just $\sum \dfrac{1}{j^2}$. I suppose something similar to $\sum j = n(n+1)/2$.

Comment: @Moron: Very likely, let's hope he won't be too disappointed :-)

Comment: @Mo: Well, Derek and me gave it as simple as it can be... again, what exactly is a "closed form"? ;)

Comment: @Derek: what you are proposing is that we find a closed form for the harmonic numbers by defining 'closed form' to include harmonic numbers! :)

Comment: @J.M: Your's is simple, but kind of circular, perhaps? I won't call the identity given by Derek to be simpler :-) I agree, though.

Comment: As I said in a previous post @Mo, polygamma functions and (generalized) harmonic numbers are virtually the same. :)

Comment: @J.M: Yep, I agree. In fact I realized that the circularity isn't there after I posted (perhaps you can add an answer?). btw, you need at least 3 letter to be able to notify :-)

Comment: But I **don't** like calling you @Moron. :P Anyway Mo, I'd rather Derek edit his answer instead; I'll only be effectively copying Derek's answer otherwise, except that the notation is different.

Comment: @J.M: :-P. Either way, as long as we have some answer which mentions that. I think it is too relevant to be left as a comment.

Comment: Anyway, as I said, [polygamma functions and generalized harmonic numbers are essentially the same banana.](http://functions.wolfram.com/06.15.27.0005.01)

Comment: Thanks, everyone~ In fact, as Moron San have said, I was looking for some "simple" expression. But I really learn much from this answer~

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this will work or not, but maybe you could try writing the expression in terms of [falling factorials](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FallingFactorial.html). Then maybe use [summation by parts](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SummationbyParts.html). I am not sure how nicely this will work, but you could try it. Let me know what you find out!

Comment: Thanks~ I will take time to have a closer look to this~

Comment: @ShinyaSakai Not a problem. Let me know what you find.