# 'Error term' in zeta function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, asymptotics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the expression of $n$ that equals to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/what-is-the-expression-of-n-that-equals-to-sum-i-1n-frac1i2)

Asymptotic formulas for the n-th harmonic number are well-known:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1n=\log n+\gamma+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{12n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)
$$
with more terms easy to generate if needed.

Is there is a similar formula for the sums of reciprocal squares?  Something like
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\cdots+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)
$$
(order negotiable, but ideally something decent like the above).

Comment: If you are interested in questions like these, Euler McLaurin ought to be in your toolbox!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you can get this from the [Euler McLaurin Summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Which according to my previous answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/14518/1102 comes to (if you only include upto $n^{-2}$)

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n} \dfrac{1}{j^2}  = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{2n^2} + \mathcal{O}(\dfrac{1}{n^3})$$

Comment: Wait.. this is a dupe... Yes: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14515/what-is-the-expression-of-n-that-equals-to-sum-i-1n-frac1i2

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalized_harmonic_numbers) gives the identity

$$\int_0^a H_{x,2}\;\mathrm dx=a\frac{\pi^2}6-H_a$$

where $H_{n,m}=\sum_{k=0}^n k^{-m}$ and $H_n = H_{n,1}$. It may be useful to get an approximation.