# Prove that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(n+i\right)^{2}}\sim\frac1{2n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, square-numbers

I would like a proof of the asymptotic relationship $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(n+i\right)^{2}}\sim\frac1{2n}$$

without assuming that the sum is a Riemann sum.

This problem arose from [Question 1909556](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909556/riemann-sum-of-1-x2?noredirect=1&lq=1), which asks about the Riemann sum of $\int_1^2\frac1{x^2}\ \mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{n^2}{(n+i)^2}=\frac12$. It features a nebulous clue that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac1{i^2}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac1{i^2}}{1/n}=\frac12$. I can't figure out how this clue works but one way of showing it could be with the asymptotic relationship is true, and from calculations, it seems to work. But I can't find any feasible way of proving it without assuming the value of the integral.

I would like to avoid assuming that the sum is simply the integral so that I can prove the integral from the sum. It also seems like a fairly simple relationship, so I would imagine there could be a nice proof.

Comment: What is wrong with assuming the value of the integral?

Comment: Within the context of the integral problem, it would be circular - I wanted to see if I could prove the value of the sum without a priori knowing it was a Riemann sum. Also, it seems like a pretty easy asymptote so I'd have thought there would be a nice proof.

Comment: I've amended the question to include that I'd like to see if there's another way of showing the relationship without knowing that it's a Riemann sum for the above reason.

Comment: Approximate $\frac{1}{k^2}$ with something that telescopes, like $\frac{1}{k^2 - \frac{1}{4}}$ or $\frac{1}{k(k\pm 1)}$ and show the difference doesn't matter.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you Daniel.

Comment: See also a comment here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445371/riemann-sum-of-int-12-1-over-x2-dx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more elementary approach.

$$\frac{1}{2n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+i)(n+i-1)}$$ because the sum telescopes to $\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n}.$

So:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2n}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(n+i\right)^{2}}&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\frac{1}{(n+i)(n+i-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+i)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+i)^2(n+i-1)}\tag{1}\\&<\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^3}\\&=\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}$$

Also, the value at  (1) is positive. So we have:

$$0<\frac{1}{2}-n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+i)^2}<\frac{1}{n}$$ and hence$$n\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+i)^2}\to\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\left(n+i\right)^{2}}=\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^{2}}$$

then we can use the result indicated here

- [What is the expression of $n$ that equals to $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14515/505767)

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for. Thank you, user.

Comment: The Euler–Maclaurin one? That's kind of weird if you want to avoid integrals.

Comment: @Jam Nice to may help you!

Comment: @DanielFischer You're right; I hadn't thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way: since $\frac{1}{x^2}$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$, the [Hermite-Hadamard inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite%E2%80%93Hadamard_inequality) ensures
$$ \frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{(2n+1)(4n-1)}=\int_{n+1/2}^{2n-1/2}\frac{dx}{x^2}\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}\geq \int_{n+1}^{2n}\frac{dx}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{n(n+1)}. $$

Comment: Sure, but that assumes the integral of $1/x^2$ and, as the question points out, if you know that, you can just use the relation of the sum to a Reimann sum for $\int_1^2dx/x^2$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{n + i}^{2}} \sim
{1 \over 2n}}:\ {\large ?}}$.

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{n + i}^{2}}} =
\sum_{i = n + 1}^{2n}{1 \over i^{2}} =
\sum_{i = 1}^{2n}{1 \over i^{2}} - \sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over i^{2}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{\zeta\pars{2} - {1 \over 2n} +
2\int_{2n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x} -
\bracks{\zeta\pars{2} - {1 \over n} +
2\int_{n}^{\infty}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x}
\end{align}

In the last line I used a
[Zeta Function Identity](https://dlmf.nist.gov/25.2.E8).

Then,
$$
\bbox[15px,#ffc]{\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over \pars{n + i}^{2}}} =
{1 \over 2n} - 2\int_{n}^{2n}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x
$$
However,
$$
0 < 2\int_{n}^{2n}{\braces{x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x <
2\int_{n}^{2n}{\dd x \over x^{3}} = {3 \over 4n^{2}} <<<
{1 \over 2n} \quad \mbox{as}\ n \to \infty
$$